# git checkout <branch> -- <path> not removing deleted files

Tags: git

I have a bunch of changes in a development branch in git and I need to rebase those onto master. Rebase gets confused, so I was going to use `git checkout dev_branch -- .` to get a copy of all those changes into master and then recommit them. This works well, except the files that I removed in the dev_branch don't get removed from master when I do the git checkout. Am I missing a parameter to git checkout or is there a better way to copy the tree to master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't using rebase, you may as well just use merge, it will do what I think you are trying to do:

```
git checkout dev_branch
git merge master
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but John's answer doesn't work for me since I do not want a merge in the history. Here is my solution, in case it may help someone else (make sure your current working directory is clean to avoid adding irrelevant files):

```
git checkout -b tmp_branch master
git reset dev_branch
git add -A
git commit -m "Copying master's state"
git checkout dev_branch
git reset --hard tmp_branch
git branch -D tmp_branch
```

Suggestions to make it simpler are welcome :)